# Json file was not found in Android

Tags: c#, android, json, file, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game for mobile and can't create a normal save system because when playing on the phone the error is logged: **Could not find the file**.
I use the **persistent  data path** as it was recommended in many answers and this method works well in Editor and Windows but not in Android.
Is there something I can do about it? Additional info: I am using IL2CPP as backend. Heard that it might create problem with serialization.
Full code:

```
    using System; 
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using UnityEngine;
     using System.IO;
     
     public class JsonFileWriter : MonoBehaviour
     {
     public string path;
     public JsonData data;
     string jsonDataString;
 
     void Awake(){
         path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "savegames", "data.json");
         FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
          if(!Directory.Exists(path)){
             file.Directory.Create();
          }
         CheckFileExistance(path);
         DeserializeData();
         SerializeData();
     }
     public void SerializeData()
      {
         CheckFileExistance(path);
         jsonDataString = JsonUtility.ToJson(data, true);
          File.WriteAllText(path, jsonDataString);
          Debug.Log("JSon data "+ jsonDataString);
      }
       public void DeserializeData()
      {
          string loadedJsonDataString = File.ReadAllText(path);
          data = JsonUtility.FromJson<JsonData>(loadedJsonDataString);
          Debug.Log("health: " + data.healthBoostAmt.ToString() + "secondChar: " + data.secondCharacterUnlocked.ToString());
      }
 
      public void WriteData(int hp,int money,int score,int damage, bool secondChar,int moneyAmt,int charSelected){
          data = new JsonData(hp,money,score,damage,secondChar,moneyAmt,charSelected);
          SerializeData();
      }
      #region Getters and seters
      public int GetHealthBoosterAmt(){
          DeserializeData();
          return data.healthBoostAmt;
      }
      public int GetMoneyBoosterAmt(){
          DeserializeData();
          return data.moneyBoostAmt;
      }
      public int GetScoreBoostAmt(){
          DeserializeData();
          return data.scoreBoostAmt;
      }
      public int GetDamageBoostAmt(){
          DeserializeData();
          return data.damageBoostAmt;
      }
      public bool GetSecondCharBought(){
          DeserializeData();
          return data.secondCharacterUnlocked;
      }
      public int GetMoneyAmt(){
          DeserializeData();
          return data.moneyAmt;
      }
      public int GetSelectedCharID(){
          DeserializeData();
          return data.charSelected;
      }
      public string GetJsonDataString(){
          return jsonDataString;
      }
      public void SetJsonDataString(string newValue){
          //int hp,int money,int score,int damage, bool secondChar
          data = JsonUtility.FromJson<JsonData>(newValue);
          WriteData(data.healthBoostAmt,data.moneyBoostAmt,data.scoreBoostAmt,data.damageBoostAmt,data.secondCharacterUnlocked,data.moneyAmt,data.charSelected);
      }
      #endregion
      void CheckFileExistance(string filePath){
          if (!File.Exists(filePath)){
             File.Create(filePath).Close();
          }
      }
 }
 [Serializable]
  public class JsonData 
  {
      public int healthBoostAmt;
      public int moneyBoostAmt;
      public int scoreBoostAmt;
      public int damageBoostAmt;
      public bool secondCharacterUnlocked;
      public int moneyAmt;
      public int charSelected;
      public JsonData (int healthBoostAmt,int moneyBoostAmt,int scoreBoostAmt,int damageBoostAmt,bool secondCharacterUnlocked,int moneyAmt,int charSelected)
      {
          this.healthBoostAmt = healthBoostAmt;
          this.moneyBoostAmt = moneyBoostAmt;
          this.scoreBoostAmt = scoreBoostAmt;
          this.damageBoostAmt = damageBoostAmt;
          this.secondCharacterUnlocked = secondCharacterUnlocked;
          this.moneyAmt = moneyAmt;
          this.charSelected = charSelected;
      }
      
      public JsonData (){}
  }
```

Comment: Please include the full error output including (partial) stack trace into your question.

Comment: @Robert Lost stack trace yesterday,deleted it by mistake but I have a screenshot
https://i2.paste.pics/6e18b358ed08b37bb33a5e4193dd7190.png